# How does suspended animation work in “Earth 2”?

Tags: suspended-animation, earth-2

In the TV show *[Earth 2](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108758/)*, the colonists spent the trip to the new planet in suspended animation. Was there any explanation, or hints about how the suspended animation worked (like cold storage)?

Comment: In the episode "All About Eve" I remember a crashed ship with suspension pods they referred to as cold sleep crypts.  You'd have to watch it to confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't remember much in-depth discussion of the hibernation technology on this show, but there are a few details that I do remember.

- Cold sleep was a form of suspended animation.  In particular, no aging occurs while a person is in cold sleep.  The voyage to planet G889 was supposed to take something like 20 years, but the characters did not age in this time.  The extreme example of this is the pilot, Alonzo Solace, who has taken several long cold-sleep journeys and is significantly older than the rest of the characters, despite appearing to be in his early 30s; in the episode "Natural Born Grendlers", he has a dream in which he sees a woman he once loved, now elderly with grandchildren.  Also, at the end of the finale, "All About Eve",

> Devon is placed in cold sleep to stop the progress of whatever mysterious disease she is suffering from.

- The technology to do this was complicated and couldn't be done in the conditions the advance team was experiencing on the planet.  In  "Natural Born Grendlers", Alonzo asks Julia to put him into cold sleep, because he is having trouble adjusting to being out of cold sleep for so long.  Julia refuses, saying (among other things) that she doesn't have the necessary equipment or supplies.  Another example of this is shown in "All About Eve", where a 100-year-old ship from Earth is found containing several scientists in cold sleep.  However, the technology has deteriorated sufficiently that when Morgan tries to bring them out of cold sleep, only one or two of them survive.
- In "A Memory Play", we meet another small group of survivors from the crash who are suffering from a virus.  One of the side effects of the virus is that the sufferers recover memories that they had previously lost, including those from immediately after they came out of cold sleep on the advance ship.  The implication was that it is difficult, under normal circumstances, to remember what happens immediately after emerging from cold sleep.

Answer (score 1):

The [novelisation for the pilot episode](https://www.goodreads.com/series/53743-earth-2) indicated that the form of suspended animation used is [cryogenics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryogenics), freezing the body inside the tube and then unfreezing it when it arrives at the destination.

> A long stretch was the first thing in order after such a long
> cryo-sleep, and Alonzo took his time about it, glorying in the
> sensation like a cat after a long nap. He cracked his knuckles, popped
> one wrist joint twice, scratched his short, bristly growth of beard,
> and sprang out of the cold-sleep tube with the agility of an elf.

Prior to freezing, various drugs are injected into the body, referred to as "prep drugs".

> Julia’s image reflected off the cockpit’s front windows. Even after
> such a profound cold sleep, with her hair slightly disheveled and her
> eyes bleary with the aftereffects of the prep-drugs, she was still a
> knockout.

At least one of those drugs is a sedative.

> Julia stepped forward from where she’d been waiting at a discreet
> distance, bent to place a sedi-derm against Uly’s neck, and pressed
> the activator. Almost immediately, his eyes fluttered closed and his
> shallow breathing slowed.